# How to pass the password as argument in Powershell script and convert to secure string

Tags: powershell

I am using below powershell script to execute

```
param([string]$Server,[string]$locusername,[string]$locpassword)

$password = '$locpassword' | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = $locusername 
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
```

and i am getting error

> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand

Comment: I don't get that error. Clearly you are using the quotes wrong (just leave them off) but even when you use the literal value of `'$locpassword'`, this is valid input for ConvertTo-SecureString and should not throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

As already mentioned by @Swonkie in the comments

There is no need to quote the parameter. Just use the parameter as provided.

```
param([String]$Server, [String]$locusername, [String]$locpassword)
process {
    #NOTE: no quotes on parameter $locpassword
    $secure_password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $locpassword -AsPlainText -Force
    $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($locusername, $secure_password)
    #...other code
}
```

If you are still getting that error then review the value stored in `$locpassword` as it may have been assigned a `$null` value.

Comment: Have used without quotes,  $password = $locpassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force,     BUt still i am getting error  Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand

Comment: how call you your ps1?

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
$password = '$locpassword' | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
```

with this:

```
$password = ($locpassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force)
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  While your answer does address the question, please include a brief explanation of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**it will be work**

```
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "******" -AsPlainText
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! While your answer may answer the question, please include a brief explanation of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(
    [Parameter(Position=1,Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Source UserName")]
    [string]$srcUsername,
    [Parameter(Position=2,Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Source Password")]
    [SecureString]$strsrcPassword,
    [Parameter(Position=3,Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Destination UserName")]
    [string]$dstUsername,
    [Parameter(Position=4,Mandatory=$True,HelpMessage="Destination Password")]
    [SecureString]$dstPassword
)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

use $locpassword or "$locpassword" , not  '$locpassword'  ;)

[image: example here]

Comment: Why the quotes? They are unnecessary.

Comment: Have used without quotes,  $password = $locpassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force,     BUt still i am getting error  Cannot bind argument to parameter 'String' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand

Answer (score -2):

instead of using single quotes use double quotes , for string expansion

```
$password = "$locpassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
```

full code:

```
param([string]$Server,[string]$locusername,[string]$locpassword)

$password = "$locpassword" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force 
$username = $locusername 
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)
```

Comment: No need to put any quotes around the variable if the variable is already a string. Just use `$locpassword`.